# Is it possible to cache API requests somehow?

Tags: api, caching, cryptocurrency

please tell me I have a cryptocurrency exchanger. I am getting a currency from API. I am running out of request traffic quickly.
Is it possible to cache API requests somehow?
Please share the correct solution to this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm just in real time, upon request, I get api request

Comment: Well, what approaches to caching have you considered?